# 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value' exception while deleting an item

Tags: sitecore-client

While deleting any item in Content Editor I'm getting

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

[image: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path]

I checked log files and the full stack trace is as follows:

```
ERROR Error while deleting items
Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:deleted' event.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.RaiseDeletedItem(Item item, ID parentId, Boolean result)
   at Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.DoArchiveItems(IEnumerable`1 items, ID archivalId)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
   at Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive.ArchiveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.Delete(List`1 items)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.DeleteItems.Execute(ClientPipelineArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Message: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ExperienceAnalyticsSegmentReader.GetDefinitionTypeKey()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ExperienceAnalyticsSegmentReader.Get(Guid key, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.Events.SegmentDeployedEventHandler.DeleteSegment(Item deletedItem)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
```

Does anyone have any idea what can be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked `SegmentDeployedEventHandler` functionality and digged in the code deep enough to find that it calls `IReferenceDataClient.EnsureDefinitionType`.

In my case it was using `ReferenceDataHttpClient` to get the data from Sitecore Reference Data Service and that service site was for some reason stopped on IIS Server.

So instead of returning json response it was a 404 response from IIS.

After starting XRef site again, exception while deleting items was gone.